# Rails 3 - How do I dynamically create an html element that is associated with a param[:id]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm attempting to implement a Rails 3 application that needs to use the html5 drawing canvas.

So far I have a Sketch scaffold and I've modified the **index** and **show** views to be side-by-side (I typed the hidden **div** in there just to show that I plan to host the canvas in a div):

[image]

Currently in the **application.js** file I have a script that accesses the show action through an Ajax request and places it right next to the Sketches list.  Here is the code for that:

```
//  Show individual sketch  
$(function(){
  var $sketch_div = $('#show_sketch_div');        

  // return html instead of js
  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:beforeSend', function(e, xhr, settings){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, text/html, ' + settings.accepts.html);
  });

  // Handle sketch name links with the data-remote attribute
  $('a[data-remote]').live('ajax:success', function(xhr, data, status){
    $sketch_div
      .html(data)         
      .show();
  });    
});
```

Also, each of the links in the Sketches list has a class associated with it (in order to grab it with JQuery):

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', sketch, :remote => true, :class => 'show_sketch_button' %></td>
```

I have the Sketch controller set up to render JSON:

> def show
>       @sketch = Sketch.find(params[:id])
>
> ```
> respond_to do |format|
>   format.html # show.html.erb
>   format.xml  { render :xml => @sketch }
>   format.json { render :json => @sketch }
> end
> ```
>
> end

This part is where I'm really stuck.

I plan on using JQuery to insert a Canvas tag whenever a Sketch's **show** button is clicked.  However, I have no idea how to get the **id** paramater of the associated sketch with Javascript and then use that to generate a Canvas element that is only associated with that particular **id**.

I've searched for JSON tutorials but I can't find anything that seems to address what I'm trying to do.  I'm also very new to JSON - so I could just be missing it.

Does anyone have any ideas or an example that you can point me to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm right, you wanna write the ID of a sketch object into your html, to use that later on with JavaScript.

Create a "data-" html5 attribute into your link_to tag. In html5 you can create tags beginning with "data-" witch are going to be valid.

```
<%= link_to 'Show', sketch, :remote => true, :class => 'show_sketch_button', :"data-sketch-id" => sketch.id %>
```

In jQuery, you can get this element with `$('a.show_sketch_button[data-sketch-id="<NUMBER>"]')`

Btw, i wouldn't recommend using .live event handling. Its parsing the full DOM every time there's a change in it. Instead of, just use .bind(), .unbind() <--- if u need to remove the eventhandler.

Comment: Doh!  I forgot all about the 'data-' attribute.  I got it to work, but needed to use alert(this.getAttribute('data-sketch-id')); in order to check and see if I had the correct values.  Otherwise it returned 'null'.  Thanks - your tips got me there!

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you used a colon when setting the id:  :"data-sketch-id".  Is this creating a symbol in rails?  It seems to pass that value as a class attribute to the html page whether or not the colon is there.  Just curious.

Comment: i did put those in a colon because of the "-" sign. It's a html_option parameter for the link_to method. For more info check:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to